# How to pipe 7z output to 7z

Tags: pipe, 7zip

I'm writing a bash script which should extract content of one 7z file and compress that extracted content to a new 7z file. The command I've tried is
    `7z x -o/tmp/ "/home/file1.7z" | 7z a -t7z "/home/file2.7z"`

Comment: It's not possible unless `7za` is reading a single file from `stdin`.

Answer (score 12):

ok, found out how to do it: `7z x "/home/file1.7z" -so | 7z a -si "/home/file2.7z"` "so" switch is needed, meaning that instead of extracting content to folder it should extract to stdout, same analogy goes for "si" switch.